# R shiny text input width size

Tags: r, shiny

I am attempting to decrease the width of my text boxes with the following code that places them side by side but I am getting no change.

```
textInputRow <-function (inputId, label, value = "") 
{
    div(style="display:inline-block",
        tags$label(label, `for` = inputId), 
        tags$input(id = inputId, value = value),
        tags$style(type="text/css", width = '50px'))
}

textInputRow(inputId="40.1", label="40", value = ''),
textInputRow(inputId="40.2", label="", value = ''),
```

Comment: Why not just `textInput(id, label, value, width = "50px")`? You can put those inside a `fluidRow` or `fixedRow`, in different columns, to make them side-by-side.

Comment: Not familiar with fluid/fixed rows. I'll give it a try. Is it possible to utilize fluidrow within a sidebarPanel?

Comment: I don't think I have tried that myself, but afaik they are very flexible and can be used pretty much anywhere.